What is this insect found in an apartment in Brazil?
I found some insects after moving into a new apartment in south eastern Brazil, in an urban center. It is the 11th floor (relatively high up) but very windy region.
Some loose wings can be found around the house. I'm not sure if they are being blown through the windows or if we have an infestation somewhere.
Some individuals were found inside bathroom cabinets. I've found two live ones with wings last night, one of which is shown in the pictures. A dead one without wings was also shown.







I think that these are termites (AKA white ants).
Termites have a flying form known as Alates (meaning "winged ones"), which commonly swarm and then shed their wings to find a place to nest once mated. The head form with the stripy antennae and long wings relative to the body make me think that these are termites.
This does not mean that you have an infestation, it could be that you have a nearby nest that is swarming, but the presence of dropped wings indicates that male and female alates have mated and are now looking for a place to build their nest. You should get your building checked out by a pest control expert.
More information on swarming termites can be found on the linked page from North Carolina State Extension

It's 100% that, I'd just like to share that's common for them to do their nuptial flight when it starts to get hotter here, between August and November (big country, could vary even more than that). So yeah, prepare to see them yearly.

That is what I feared. Well, pest control it is. Thanks for the help.
